# What are the drawbacks of Harris corner detector?

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction

What are drawbacks of Harris corner detection when trying to match features in a stereo pair? I notice that whenever I use Harris corner detector to match features, images with strong occluded areas are matched incorrectly.